# Repeated IBM bluemix Node Red app crashing; status 1

Tags: crash, ibm-cloud, node-red

My Node Red application in IBM BlueMix is repeatedly crashing - once an hour - with no real error message other than "`exited with status: 1.`"

- How can I troubleshoot this issue?
- Is there someone from IBM BlueMix support that monitors this that could take a look?

I looked at my logs and there's nothing in there that really says what's going on.

Edit per requests:

The regular log for "OUT/ERR" is scrolling so fast with HTTPD logs that I can't get it to copy/paste. Filtering to "ERR" Channel the only thing I see is below. I believe this is an error which occurs during deploy when the application restarts.

[App/0] ERR js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version

My Node Red application is gathering data from Wink, LIFX, and other IoT services and compiles them together into a Freeboard dashboard.

[Caught crash on screenshot here -- not enough cred to post images so it'll only post as a link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ja59Y.png)

Comment: Please edit your question to include the log output to see if we can see something more in it. Also some description about what your node-red flow is doing would be useful

Comment: Did you create your Node-RED environment using the "Node-RED" starter? ... https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/starters/node-red-starter/

Comment: Is there some where I can get the log as a file instead of through the Overview -> Logs pane? The HTTP messages are scrolling too fast and it won't let me select anything.

Comment: @Kolban - I used the Boilerplate for Node Red which includes Cloudant DB.

Comment: In your Bluemix dashboard, select your application and in the application area, you will find entries for "Files" and "Logs".  In there you should find the histories of your runs.

Comment: @Kolban - the only log I have in the Logs directory is staging log, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

The zlib error was fixed in the 0.13.2 Node-RED [release](https://github.com/node-red/node-red/releases/tag/0.13.2) (that shipped 19/02/16).

If you re-stage your application is should pick up the new version of Node-RED

You can re-stage the application using the cf command line management application:

```
cf restage <app name>
```

Comment: My project is on Blue Mix's github - is there something I can change in package.json to force it to use 0.13.2 Node Red?

And dumb question - but any ideas as to why this would just start happening out of the blue? I haven't had this issue for months and I know plenty of others using 13.1 without issue?

Comment: The boilerplate code will always pick up the latest version from npm on a redeploy/restage

Comment: I was definitely not experiencing that -- I had to manually edit my package.json file to get it to pick up 0.13.2. It was ~0.13.x and was not updating.